# How to check an object is a string or an array in ios

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I am getting a response array from two different web services. But for the same methods. The problem is there 2 different web services give me bit different responses. These are those arrays

```
(NSMutableArray *) $2 = 0x003e9210 <__NSArrayM 0x3e9210>(

{

addedOn = "03/09/2013";

album = "Surendra Perera";

artistGroup = Female;

artists = "Surendra Perera";

bpm = 0;

categories = "Love Songs";

duration = "250.00";

energy = "";

era = Millenium;

extroTime = "0.00";

extroType = "";

genders = "";

id = 50;

imageUrl = "http://sample.com/CloudMusic/Images/sngfile.png";

introTime = "0.00";

language = Sinhala;

lyrics = "";

mediaUrl = "http://sample.com/CloudMusic/Music/0476/50.mp3";

moods = Lonely;

movie = "";

musicLabel = Evoke;

musician = "";

sDuration = "00:04:10";

soundCodes = "";

tempos = "";

textures = "";

thumbUrl = "http://sample.com/CloudMusic/Images/sngfile.png";

title = "Mee Mai Gaha";

writer = "";

year = "";

}

)
```

Other one is

```
addedOn = "19/09/2013";

albumName = Massina;

artists =     (

            {

        artistGroup = 0;

        description = "<null>";

        id = 290;

        imageUrl = "<null>";

        name = Daddy;

        noOfSongs = 0;

        thumbUrl = "<null>";

    }

);

duration = "260.00";

id = 2575;

imageUrl = "http://sample.com/CloudMusic/Images/sngfile.png";

mediaUrl = "http://sample.com/CloudMusic/Music/0905/2575.mp3";

sDuration = "00:04:20";

songMoods =     (

            {

        id = 3;

        name = Sad;

        noOfSongs = 0;

    }

);

thumbUrl = "http://sample.com/CloudMusic/Images/sngfile.png";

title = "Aai Kale";

year = "";

}

)
```

What I want to do is chek for this artists array. How can I check for this artists coming as an array or just a string. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will illustarate your problem
Get data rx in _recievedData then check the class of the object.

```
id object = [NSJSONSerialization
                 JSONObjectWithData:_recievedData
                 options:kNilOptions
                 error:&error];
if (error)
{
     NSLog(@"Error in rx data:%@",[error description]);
}
if([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] == YES)
{
     NSLog(@"String rx from server");
}
else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] == YES)
{
     NSLog(@"Dictionary rx from server");
}
else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] == YES)
{
     NSLog(@"Array rx from server");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.

```
id object = [responseData objectForKey:@"artists"];

if ([object isMemberOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    // do the stuff for NSString
}
else if ([object isMemberOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    // do the stuff for NSArray
}
```